# How to unit test a class that uses context?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I'm trying to test a simple method.

I have this class:

```
class Cloud @Inject constructor(var posx: Double = 0.0, var posy: Double = 0.0, var velocity: 
    Double = 1.0, val context: Context){

    val image: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.raw.cloud)

    fun updateVelocity(){
        velocity += 5.0
    }

    fun draw(canvas: Canvas){
        canvas.drawBitmap(image,posx.toFloat() - (image.width / 2),posy.toFloat(),null)
    }    
}
```

I want to unit test the `updateVelocity()` method but i can't figure out how, should i use an instrumental test and pass the context or can i use something like mockk?

Can i do this with mockk?

```
@Test
fun cloudVelocity() { 
    val cloud: Cloud = mockk()                
    //update cloud velocity
    //assert that the velocity changed 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case is very hard to unit test yours class because it depends not only on context, but also on `Bitmap`, `BitmapFactory` and `Canvas`.

Maybe will be better if you separate business and drawing logic at different classes. For example yours `Cloud` object will contain only pure business logic and you could easily test it. On the other hand you could create `CloudDrawer` class that will contain drawing logic with `Canvas/Context/Bitmap`

In most simper cases you could replace `Context` by using special interface. For example we use `getString()` in our classes. But we want to test these classes. And in this case we use this abstraction over `Context`:

```
interface ResourceManager {
    fun getColor(@ColorRes resId: Int): Int
    fun getDrawable(@DrawableRes resId: Int): Drawable?
    fun getString(@StringRes resId: Int): String
    fun getString(@StringRes resId: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): String
    fun getStringArray(@ArrayRes resId: Int): Array<String>
    fun getQuantityString(@PluralsRes resId: Int, quantity: Int, formatArgs: Int): String
}
```

And it's easy to mock this interface:

```
 val resource = mock(ResourceManager::class.java)
 `when`(resource.getString(any(Int::class.java))).thenReturn("text")
```